# Error on setting state inside useEffect hook (Rendered fewer hooks than expected)

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks

I'm building a login screen for a React Native app, suddenly, while I was working on another page, the login screen began throwing the "Rendered Fewer Hooks than Expected" error. I tried erasing the "setState" lines inside the useEffect and that seemed to stop the error, but they are still needed for the page to work...

Here's the code for the page:

```
export function Login(props: ILogin) {
    const isFocused = useIsFocused();

    const [email, setEmail] = useState<string>("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState<string>("");
    const [operators, setOperators] = useState<IOperator[]>([]);

    useEffect(() => {        
        if (!operators[0]) {
            (async () => {
                const response = await Rest.getOperators();

                if (response.error) {
                    console.log(response.error.msg);
                } else {
                //The error seems to be here, if any state is set inside the useEffect, the error occurs
                setOperators(response);
                }
            })();
        }

    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
        //To make sure that if this page is returned to, the email and password will be reset, the error still happens without this useEffect
        //The error doesn't happen here as long as the value set is ""
        setEmail("");
        setPassword("");
    }, [isFocused])

    return (
        <Page>
            //--
        </Page>
    )
}
```

I've already tried commenting lines of code until coming to the conclusion that the "setState" is the one causing the error. I've already tried deleting and reinstalling the node_modules, cleaning the cache and rebuilding the app, but still, the same error occurs.

Comment: What does `useIsFocused` do? All the rest of the code looks fine to me.

Comment: My question is, you are setting `useState<IOperator[]>([]);` to an initially empty array -- Are you sure that in `setOperators(response);` "response" is an array?

Comment: @NicholasTower maybe I should've added my imports... useIsFocused is imported from react navigation. If my understanding is correct... It should tell whether the page is active or not.

Comment: @Zak Yes, I've used console.log and even looked into the backend. It always returns an array of the exact same type of IOperator[]. If it doesn't it falls on the response.error above it

Comment: Does adding `operators` to the list of dependencies of the first `useEffect` change anything? The provided example works fine in regular react, so I guess this is related to the interplay between useIsFocused and the dynamic fetch. Fetching the data in a wrapper component might help.

Comment: I deleted my wrong answer, assuming it had to do with calling hooks conditionally, which is not the case here, at least not in the code you shared.

I do think though, that the example here doesn't tell the whole story.

Comment: @matthiasgiger So, adding `operators` to the list of dependencies did not work. But using a wrapper component and deleting the useIsFocused did!! I got to find another way of resetting the values, but at least that errors doesn't happen anymore!

Comment: @AntonPodolsky It's not the whole code, I omitted a few irrelevant things, functions that aren't called on render, for example.